Adobe Acrobat registers a custom URI scheme, but includes an unexplained /u flag?
We are trying to integrate with the Adobe Acrobat custom URI scheme, e.g. allowing users to launch links of the format acrobat:https://localhost/example.pdf
This will launch Adobe Acrobat, but it appears to ignore the file.
On deeper inspection we see that the custom URI scheme launches acrobat.exe followed by a /u flag, and then finally the link in the URI.
So it effectively launches the following command which does not appear to load the document at the URI.
acrobat.exe /u https://localhost/example.pdf
Does anyone know what this /u flag is?
What can I provide following the /u flag to get Adobe Acrobat to launch the PDF at the provided URI?
